# Does all traffic that passes through the docker swarm ports (2377, 7946, 4789) encrypted?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am currently exploring and experimenting with docker swarm and came across this part in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/overlay/#encrypt-traffic-on-an-overlay-network):

> All swarm service management traffic is encrypted by default, using
> the AES algorithm in GCM mode. Manager nodes in the swarm rotate the
> key used to encrypt gossip data every 12 hours.

Does this mean that all data that passes through these ports are encrypted? I am most interested about the service discovery traffic which seems to be related to port 7946.